# Qml Flickable Pages

Tags: qt, menu, symbian, nokia, qml

If I wanted to create a flickable looping page menu basically like the Symbian home screen, what element would I use a possibly how would I use it?

I have tried creating "page" elements in QML and then creating a flickable element with 3 pages on, when you flick the pages are changed according to a list and then the fickable is centered allowing you to loop through the pages but it isn't nearly as smooth as the native Symbian home screen. It doesn't finish the flick to the next page automatically; it also doesn't detect slow flicks which results in the pages not being changed and centered meaning you have to flick in the other direction and then back. It is also a bit confusing having to make the page on the flickable equal to another one on the list so I would like to be able to place all the pages on the element instead of having to swap pages. I haven't actually figured out how to swap pages yet as I am just still experimenting with colored rectangles and have noticed the above problems.

I think I should rather use something like Listview but I can't figure out how. If you have any idea's or experience with this, please help!

Comment: i think you can use QML Pathview (http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-pathview.html)

Comment: Thanks I've got that working but do you know how I can get it limited to flick only one element or index at a time instead of going through a lot of them if you flick fast?

Comment: might be this blog will help (http://kunalmaemo.blogspot.com/2010/12/simple-view-switching-animation-with-qt.html), I think you need to implement view switching your self. You might also need to implement your custom gesture handler to detect swipe and switch view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should be using a `ListView`. With `snapMode` set to `ListView.SnapOneItem`.

Comment: I will be using PathView and in Qt 5 I will have a SnapOneItem option for it.